# When to use complement when finding probability

Tags: probability

In a scientific study there are 8 guinea pigs, 5 if which are pregnant. If 3 are selected at random without replacement, find the probability that are all pregnant?

And the answer is 5/28.

But when finding the probability that none are pregnant, the answer is 1/56 since (3/8)(2/7)(1/6) = 1/56.

Why can't we use complement upon solving this? And subtract 1 from 5/28?

Answer (score 5):

There a 5 guinea pigs that are pregnant. On the first draw, you have a 5/8 chance of selecting a pregnant one. What do you think the chances are on the second draw?

For your part of the question "why can't I use the complement rule?". You can, but it's not as simple as $P(\bar{A}) = 1- P(A)$. What you have (1/56) is the probability of drawing NO pregnant guinea pigs. The complement of "drawing NO pregnant guinea pigs" is "at least one guinea pig is pregnant".

Comment: Nice answer (+1). Appeared while I was writing about the hypergeometric distribution.

Comment: Thanks! I've seen a few of your answers recently. I think your inclusion of R is a nice touch :)

Answer (score 2):

**Short answer:** The probability of getting 3 pregnant guinea pigs when 3 are chosen at random from the 8, is 
$$\frac{{5 \choose 3}{3 \choose 0}}{{8\choose 3}} =  \frac{5}{28} = 0.1786.$$
Computations in R:

```
choose(5,3)/choose(8,3)
[1] 0.1785714
5/28
[1] 0.1785714
```

**More detail:** Let $X$ be the number of pregnant guinea pigs in a sample of 3 chosen at random without replacement from the 8 in the study. Then $X$ has a [hypergeometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution#targetText=In%20probability%20theory%20and%20statistics,a%20success%20or%20a%20failure.) with PDF:

$$P(X = k) = \frac{{5 \choose k}{3 \choose 3-k}}{{8\choose 3}},$$
for $k = 0,1,2,3.$ We can use the PDF function `dhyper` in R to make
the distribution table.

```
k = 0:3;  pdf = dhyper(k, 5,3, 3)
cbind(k, pdf)

     k        pdf
[1,] 0 0.01785714
[2,] 1 0.26785714
[3,] 2 0.53571429
[4,] 3 0.17857143
```

**About complements:** The reason you can't take the complement as you propose, is that the complement of "no (0) pregnant guinea pigs" is *not* "all (3) pregnant guinea pigs." There are other possible outcomes: specifically, either 1 or 2 pregnant. The complement of "no pregnant guinea pigs" in the sample is "at least one pregnant guinea pig."

$$P(X \ge 1) = 1 - P(X = 0).$$

**Bar graph of PDF:** Here is a graph of the hypergeometric PDF of $X.$

[image]